# Simple file manager with version control

Tags: php, version-control

As the title suggests, I am looking for a simple file manager script that has some form of version control system built into it.

My needs are:

1. It needs to be web based (written in PHP using MySQL for storage)
2. I need to be able to edit the files without moving them. (In other words if a file resides in `/public_html/somedir/somefile.php` , I want to be able to edit it from there without the need of creating a new project folder just to house this one file.)
3. A basic no frills file editor will be fine, but it would be nice to have some form of syntax highlighter built in if possible.
4. Needs to have a very basic version control system where I can add, edit, delete different versions of a file I am working on. (this is where the database comes in)
5. Must be able to support multiple users with some sort of file locking to prevent 2 users from editing the same file at the same time.
6. It needs to be free / open source.

Basically, all I want is a script that will allow me to login to it and present me with a list of all the files and directories located on my hosting account. I would then like to be able to select one of these files, save a copy of it to my database so I can recover it if need be, edit the file, and finally overwrite the original file with my edited version when I am done.

Answer (score 2):

Google docs does most of this...

Comment: It doesn't do it on my server tho and I need to house the script on my server for various reasons.

Comment: Care to elaborate why?

Comment: Reasons: Google will not automatically list all the files on my serveer. From what I have read, it will also not automatically places the edited files back onto my server. I really cannot talk about it's version control or multiple user features as I have not used it for that, but the first 2 reasons are enough of a deal breaker for me. Thx tho.

Comment: approximatly how many files are we talking about?

Comment: best estimate would be 50,000+. I want to be able to edit ANY ASCII based file on my server, this includes all the files from any 3rd party scripts that I have on my site like fourms, blogs, CMS system, etc. As I said I want to be able to edit ANY of those files at will.

Comment: So any suggestionss....